# VBA code to grab all files in folder is not finding files

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to set up a macro to pull all excel files in a folder into a database in access. I have the below code, but when I run the macro, it errors out into "No Files Found," so intFile = 0. However, there are files in the chosen folder. Why is it not finding them? I think I messed up the linking piece too but one problem at a time. I am obviously pretty new to VBA, so any help would be appreciated!
Thanks,

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'code will link to excel and pull site survey files into access tables

'Setting the path for the directory

Const strPath As String = "S:\LOG\PURCHASI\Daniel Binkoski\Outlook Attachments\R7398Z Look Forward Daily Snapshot"

'FileName
Dim strFile As String
'Array
Dim strFileList() As String
'File Number
Dim intFile As Integer

Sub Sample()

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
    'Looping through the folder and building the file list
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
    While strFile <> ""
        'adding files to the list
        intFile = intFile + 1
        ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
        strFileList(intFile) = strFile
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend

    'checking to see if files where found
    If intFile = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Files Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'going through the files and linking them to access
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , _
        strFileList(intFile), strPath & strFileList(intFile), True, "A1:M50"
    Next

    MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & "Files were linked"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
```

or add a final "\" onto your strPath value

You need another path separator to show you're looking *in* a directory, not *at* one.

I often use something like:

```
Dir(strPath & IIf(Right(strPath, 1) = "\", vbNullString, "\"))
```

as a check to ensure that the path always ends in a trailing backslash.